# free provider for .well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, verification

Is there any free provider for .well-known/openid-configuration available so that we can do verification of JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

You verify JWT tokens using configuration provided by the service which issued the JWT token. The service which issued the tokens and signed them is responsible for providing any public keys needed to verify the JWT. So that service exposes a .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint.

If you are issuing your own tokens then you should be in possession of everything needed to verify them.